# Must I back up my data before installing a second OS? What will happen if I don't back it up?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

I have Windows installed on my computer. I wish to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. Wherever I've read the instructions to do this, backing up the data is mentioned everywhere. I was wondering if it is really necessary to back up my data? What happens if I don't?

Comment: Your data may be lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something may go wrong, either due to a bug in the Ubuntu installer or you making a mistake. The Ubuntu installer has full access to your disk and is capable of destroying everything. The programmers from Canonical have used a lot of time to design an installer that won't do this unless you explicitly ask it to, but they cannot take responsibility if some mistake slipped through anyway.

In other words, making a backup is for the sake of "**better safe than sorry**".

Comment: Got it - backup is not _necessary_ but _recommended_. Thanks.