# Installing a second OS carries a risk of data loss; even your PC's user manual says so. If you have backups, is it now okay to install a second OS?

Tags: linux, security, installation, multi-boot, bsd

## Background

A variety of Samsung laptops say something like this in [their user manuals](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22If+you+install+an+OS+other+than+the+factory+OS%2C+data+may+be+deleted+or+the+computer+may+not+start.%22) (PDF):

> If you change the product's factory OS (Operating System) to another OS, or if you install software which is not supported by the product’s original factory OS: You will not receive any technical support, product exchange, or refund; and a fee will be charged when requesting ... service.
>
> Please use your computer with the original factory OS. If you install an OS other than the factory OS, data may be deleted or the computer may not start.

Recently, I was conversing with a non-native English speaker. They looked at the user manual and [misinterpreted](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/12584/which-laptops-are-appropriate-to-set-a-dual-boot-systemwindows-and-linux#comment20615_12584) Samsung's warnings. They thought Samsung meant that, if you install a second OS, data **will** be deleted. Perhaps they just misunderstood the word "may". On the other hand, perhaps they understood the word "may" perfectly fine, and are new to the Linux world, and want to know more about the risks involved.

## The risk

It's definitely true that, when installing a second operating system, there's a risk that some or all of your pre-existing data may be deleted. This can happen due to user error or due to problems with the OS installer.

## My question

Perhaps you've already backed up all your important data. Or perhaps the computer is brand-new and there's no user data stored on the machine. And you're willing to void your warranty.

In these two cases, is it reasonable to ignore Samsung's request to "please use ... the original factory OS", and is it reasonable to install whatever second OS you want?

Comment: Related question: ["Is it absolutely necessary to back up my data before installing a second OS?"](https://superuser.com/questions/756177/is-it-necessary-to-backup-data-before-installing-second-os)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have no idea what another OS may setup, delete or what firmware configuration changes the second OS might require or provoke.

For example some Linux distributions may require you disable secure boot or other options such as enabling BIOS compatibility support which would make your current OS unbootable. Windows does not support changing from UEFI to CSM/BIOS mode and does not support booting from GPT disks under BIOS nor MBR disks under UEFI so changing that option would make Windows unbootable.

A backup might guarantee your data, but getting back to a position where that backup is usable might be non-trivial.

They are saying that it's up to you  to do what you want, but the moment you go "off the reservation" then they reserve the right to charge you to get back. They only guarantee free support for situations where the computer was used *as intended* and with the OS it was provided with.

Other than that, as long as you accept the risks and don't hold Samsung responsible for data loss (which they aren't) then you can do what you like.

Chances are that as long as you know what you are doing, know the risks and have taken appropriate measures to backup your data then everything will be fine, it is *just a computer* after all. But it can be easy for a novice to "follow some guides", Google a couple of errors and quickly end up with a machine that has been wiped, has an OS that can't work and is as good as dead until someone knowledgeable comes along.

Comment: There are factual inaccuracies in this answer: **(1)** If an OS is installed w/ Secure Boot enabled, and Secure Boot is disabled at some point afterward, that OS will remain unbootable _until_ Secure Boot is re-enabled - it does not make the OS permanently unbootable; **(2)** Secure Boot has zero to do w/ recognizing a disk or it's partitions and a disk with an OS installed w/ secure boot enabled will still have the same exact partitions w/ the same exact data when it's detected by whatever OS one tries to access the disk from.  Once factual inaccuracies are addressed, I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @JW0914 I never said "permanently", I just said "non-trivial" especially if the user is a novice following guides and doesn't know what they are changing. I listed secure boot and BIOS mode as two individual options that can make a system unbootable and makes the operating system non functional. I'll remove the apparently offensive line.

Comment: Nothing I read was offensive _(I found what you wrote to be informative)_, but a handful of words were, at the very least, unintentionally factually misleading _(I don't believe your intent is/was to be inaccurate or misleading)_.  For example, the way the wording comes across is an implication the PC will no longer be bootable via an unintentionally implied permanence.

Comment: @JW0914 i I'd use the same words myself. OP is likely a computer novice and needs to know the potential issues, and using simplified terms at this stage in their knowledge journey is a reasonable precaution.

Comment: @music2myear I understand that point of view, but I also know answers on StackExchange will be around for over a decade, with this subject matter likely remaining relevant a decade from now, so factual accuracies do matter.

Answer (score 3):

The quote basically only says that installing any other configuration than the original one is unsupported.

Which means that if you have any problems while/after installing the second OS, don't request support from the manufacturer.

In such cases, I always suggest making a backup disk image before starting, preferably with a product that has boot CD/USB support, such as [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/). This way, you'll have a way back if needed.

If you want Linux installed alongside Windows, consider the Linux distributions available for free in the Microsoft Store app: they can be a simpler alternative.